# Cual es el STRING de conexión para conectarse a SQL server con Windows Autentificacion?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Este es el String que estoy usando:

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection
        (@"Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=CarritoAndroid");
```

Debería mostrarme los registro que tengo una tabla llamada productos con un método que tengo llamado: ListarProductos. Pero me muestra un error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)

Answer (score 1):

El `connection string` esta correcto

Tu problema no pasa por la seguridad integrada en el connection string, sino que al ejecutar en un entorno web debes `impersonar` el sitio indicando un usuario de windows que si tenga acceso a la db

Por defecto cuando creas el sitio el `Application Pool` tiene un usuario y es este el que usa para intentar autenticarse en la db.

Hay dos formas de resolverlo:

1- cambiando el usuario con el cual ejecuta el sitio web, para esto se edita el `Application Pool`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alli debes poner un usuario del dominio de windows que tenga acceso a la db

2- Impersonando el sitio por medio del `web.config`

[Introduction to identity impersonation with IIS and ASP.NET](http://appetere.com/post/introduction-to-identity-impersonation-with-iis-and-aspnet)

edita el config y sino lo encuentras crea la entrada

```
 <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="[DOMAIN]\UserName" password="[Password]" />
```

donde debes definir un usuario del dominio de windows que tenga acceso a la db

lo que indica es que dentro del tag `system.web` debes crear el de `identity` si es que no existe

Comment: En password seria el password que utilizo para iniciar sesion en Windows?

Comment: si, debes usar un usuario de windows que puedas validar desde el Management Studio pueda ingresar

Comment: tambien configure el aplication pools, al agregar : <system.web> <identity impersonate="true" userName="DESKTOP-E83NLPV\Ewin_Mendez" password="201753760210" />  me muestra error de servidor y no compila, sin embargo sin agregarle lo anterior me funciona ejecutándolo desde visual estudio con el IIS Express. Al publicarlo e intentar invocar el método, muestra el error inicial de la publicación.

Comment: Gracias Ya pude configurarlo como me indico... Muchas gracias de verdad!!!!

Answer (score 0):

En el web.config tu proyecto, ve a la seccion

```
<system.web>
```

y agrega al final antes de cerrar el tag

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="tu_usuario" password="tu_pass" />
```

recompilas, publicas de nuevo tu proyecto y ya.

Comment: Estoy utlizando la Autentificacion de Windows, cual seria el usuario y el password?

Comment: si estas en un dominio, el usuario y password que utilizas para iniciar sesión en tu pc

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en el String de conexion el que debia usar es:
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-E83NLPV;Initial Catalog=CarritoAndroid;Integrated Security=True");

El String para conectarse con una base de datos de SQL server usando Autentificacion de Windows es:
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source="Nombre del servidor";Initial Catalog="Nombre de la base de datos";Integrated Security=True");

Comment: Usar `Integrated Security=True` o `Integrated Security=SSPI` no es el problema. El problema es que debes darle acceso al usuario `APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` en la seguridad de la db. O en caso contrario impersonar el sitio con un usuario que si tenga acceso